# OpenMPI with cygwin on windows?

Tags: c, cygwin, mpi

I am trying to setup cygwin and openmpi on windows. I have cygwin and I selected the openmpi packages from cygwin installer but it seems that when I try to compile my programs using `mpicc` the compiler seems to not be able to see `mpicc`. I have in my path the path to my cygwin bin.

**Update:**

Below is the error message when using command `mpicc -o bp_main_2 bp_main_2.c`

`Program 'mpicc' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
+ mpicc -o bp_main_2 bp_main_2.c
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ mpicc -o bp_main_2 bp_main_2.c
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed`

Comment: You would require installation of gcc as well as openmpi development.

Comment: yes i installed gcc and openmpi development and it still seems to not know anything about `mpicc`

Comment: If you don't provide any detailed log of the failed detection we can not guess your problem. As minimal you need `openmpi` and `libopenmpi-devel` packages

Comment: @matzeri I have added the error logs. hopefully this can help understand the problem more.

Comment: When using Cygwin terminal and using either `mpicc` or `mpirun` the compiler sees it but outside of cygwins terminal it does not see the two commands. I think I am suppose to add something to my path but I am unsure as to what.

Comment: what do you mean as `outside of cygwins terminal` ?

Comment: @matzeri if I use cygwins terminal it sees the two commands but if I use a terminal such as `cmd` or `power shell` it seems to not be able to see the commands. I added the cygwin bin to my path which I thought was the way to allow you to use `cmd` just like you would use cygwins terminal